# Handler not executing in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I am trying to build an app for class and am having trouble with handling data that is gathered in another thread. The data does not seems to being passed through the handlers `handleMessage` method.

This is my main activity

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BookListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    ArrayList<Book> names;
    private boolean twoPane = false;
    BookListFragment blf;
    BookDetailsFragment bdf;
   // Handler bookHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        twoPane = findViewById(R.id.container2) == null;
        names = new ArrayList<Book>();
        final EditText searchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
        final Handler bookHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

                String response = (String) msg.obj;
                try{
                    JSONArray tmp = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject a = tmp.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = a.getInt("book_id");
                        String title = a.getString("title");
                        Log.d("BOOK_id", a.getInt("book_id")+"");
                        String author = a.getString("author");
                        int published =  a.getInt("published");
                        String coverUrl = a.getString("cover_url");
                        Book book = new Book(id,title,author,published,coverUrl);
                        names.add(book);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("FAIL", e.toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Thread t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String searchString = searchBar.getText().toString();
                URL bookURL;
                try {
                    bookURL = new URL("https://kamorris.com/lab/audlib/booksearch.php?search="+searchString);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bookURL.openStream()));
                    String response = "",tmpResponse;
                    tmpResponse = reader.readLine();
                    while(tmpResponse != null){
                        response = response + tmpResponse;

                        tmpResponse = reader.readLine();
                    }
                    Log.d("Handler", response);

                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    msg.obj = response;
                    bookHandler.handleMessage(msg);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Fail", e.toString());
                }

            }
        };
        t.start();
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String searchString = searchBar.getText().toString();
                        URL bookURL;
                        try {
                            bookURL = new URL("https://kamorris.com/lab/audlib/booksearch.php?search="+searchString);
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bookURL.openStream()));
                            String response = "",tmpResponse;
                            tmpResponse = reader.readLine();
                            while(tmpResponse != null){
                                response = response + tmpResponse;
                                tmpResponse = reader.readLine();
                            }
                            JSONArray bookOBJ= new JSONArray(response);
                            Message msg = Message.obtain();
                            msg.obj = bookOBJ;
                            bookHandler.handleMessage(msg);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("Fail", e.toString());
                        }

                    }
                };
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

The code is suppose to get data from an api and then in the `handleMessage` method it is suppose to parse the data into a book object that contains two int and three string variables. The problem is that the handler never executes any code.

The execution should be that the debugger log should have the response string with the data from the API and then the id of every book in the JSON file, but it only has the data from the api displayed.

Comment: Make use of Retrofit or Volley itself for better, quick, reliable and easy handling of api calls

Comment: Don't call `handleMessage()` yourself. Use `sendMessage()` instead. `Handler`'s own `handleMessage()` method is empty, and since you've given the `Handler` a `Callback` object instead of directly overriding the class method, calling `bookHandler.handleMessage()` does nothing. Also, there's really no reason you can't do that JSON processing and `List` building on the worker `Thread`, too. The only thing you really need to do in that `Handler` is update the UI; e.g., setting `TextView`s, notifying `Adapter`s, etc.